# click button to open dial pad, this string for example String str = "*#06#" should be open in dial pad.?

Tags: java, buttonclick

My Code is this:

```
public void onclickdial(View v) {
String str = "*#06#";
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:"+str)));
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
```

but there is a problem only * symbol is displayed on dial screen:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        String str = "*#06#";
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.fromParts("tel", str, ","));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    startActivity(callIntent);
```

or:

```
        String str = "*#06#";
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:"+ Uri.encode(str))));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Thanx you very much